# Using Jackson XML binding to map lists to Pojo

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-binding

I am using Jackson's XML binding to convert XML into a Java List, via an initial mapping to a Java POJO.  What I have written works but I don't think I am using Jackson correctly.

I am stuck with this ugly XML:

```
<groups>
  <groups>One</groups>
  <groups>Two</groups>
  <groups>Three</groups>
</groups>
```

Here is the Java POJO I am using.  Note the `setGroups(String)` method is actually adding to the list.

```
public class Groups {
   private List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();

   public void setGroups(String group) {
      groups.add(group);
   }

   public List<String> getGroups() { 
      return this.groups;
   }
}
```

Here is how I invoke Jackson's XmlMapper.

```
public List<String> getListOfGroups(String xmlDoc) {
   XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
   Groups groups = mapper.readValue(xmlDoc, Groups.class);
   return groups.getGroups();
}
```

This is actually working as I need it to work. I get a Groups class with a list populated with the elements I expect.  I am wondering, is approach is correct? I don't like that I have a setter doing an add but everything I've tried has not worked.

Comment: Could you change XML? `groups` node with `groups` subnodes does not look good.

Comment: I have no control over the XML, I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your POJO could be simple like this:

```
public class Groups {
    private List<String> groups;

    public List<String> getGroups() { 
        return this.groups;
    }
}
```

It will work fine since you use the [MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS) (enabled by default).